# IntelliJ set public/static folder in a web project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a web project in IntelliJ Ultimate and I am using different folders for my views and the public directory (due to using Node.js & Express):

`├── public
│   └── test.css
└── views
    └── index.html`

I want to use simple paths in my index.html, like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css"/>`

but IntelliJ shows an error because it can't find test.css in my index.html:

[image: cannot resolve file test.css]

How can I map the public directory to `public/` so that `/test.css` resolves internally to `public/test.css`?

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the folder, in your case is 'public', then `Mark Directory as` > `Resources Root`.

[image]

Tested on **IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1**

Answer (score 1):

You can try marking those directories as source as below:

Right click on project > Open module settings > Select your module:

Then under sources tab, navigate to your directories and click `Mark as sources`.

Comment: This does not work because (I think) this is only used for specific Java Web projects. I have tried it but neither "Mark as Sources" nor "Mark as Resources" worked.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in the Ultimate version:

1. Open File / Project Structure settings (⌘; or Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
2. If not already there, select Modules in the left sidebar.
3. Click + to add new Module named Web.
4. Map web folder in the Web Resource Directories section (eg. ./public to /)
   (5. You may need to use the inspect dialog in your html/template files to use this mapping.)

Based on: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-application-static-content.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggle with this:
If your project structure is:

```
├── public
│   └── test.css
└── views
│   └── index.html
└── src
    └── app.ts
```

To make the IDE recognize public path in index.html file, remember to mark the *public* folder as Resource root **AND** mark the *views* folder as source root along with the src folder too.